# Why valign in table bad working with TEXTAREA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

```
<table border="1" style="height:200px">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">January<textarea></textarea></td>
    <td valign="bottom">$100</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BCsN2/

January should be equally with top textarea. How can I make it? Maybe with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the 1st solution, by splitting it over 2 cells. Don't forget to add colspan to the above cells.

```
<table border="1" style="height:200px">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Month</th> <!-- add colspan="2" -->
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">January</td> <!-- split it to 2 cells (#1) -->
    <td valign="top"><textarea></textarea></td> <!-- split it to 2 cells (#2) -->
    <td valign="bottom">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the 2nd solution, by using CSS:

```
<table border="1" style="height:200px">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <span style="float: left">January</span> <!-- wrap it in span and add CSS float -->
        <textarea style="float: left"></textarea> <!-- add CSS float -->
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
textarea { vertical-align: top }
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BCsN2/5/
and instead of using `valign` as `<td>` attribute, use `vertical-align` as style property

Comment: His issue is the fact that the textarea is clearly aligned to the top of the cell, but "January" is not.

Comment: There's a gap above "January".  He's saying that it's not truly top aligned.

Comment: the alignment is right. line-height has of course its impact.

Comment: But what you posted has nothing to do with the word "January".  He says "January should be equally with top textarea. How can i make it?"

Comment: Actually, I've been running it in Chrome and I just tried it in IE and Firefox and it aligns January with the bottom of the textarea.  It's actually worse than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

you can use one more nested table. It's probably the easiest way for this (no JS required).
The only problem is that, most probably you will need to specify some additional CSS rules (styles) for this nested table. So it won't inherit anything from the parent one.

```
<table border="1" style="height:200px">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle">January</td>
          <td valign="middle"><textarea></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom">$100</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```